# fullcalendar not updating time

Tags: jquery, datetime, date, fullcalendar

In my xml date comes like

```
<Action>
     ...
     <Started>05/10/2011 15:48:10</Started>
     ...
     <Done>05/10/2011 17:48:17</Done>
...
  </Action>
```

and Code I have written something like

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek'
        },
        editable: false,
        slotMinutes: 60,
       events: function(start, end, callback) {
            var events = [];
            var count=0;
            $(ActivityXML).find('Action').each( function() {
              alert(calendarFormat($(ActivityXML).find('Action').eq(count).find("Started").text()));
                events.push({
                    title: $(ActivityXML).find('Action').eq(count).find("Type").text(),
                    start:$(ActivityXML).find('Action').eq(count).find("Started").text(),
                    end:$(ActivityXML).find('Action').eq(count).find("Done").text(),

                });
                count++;
            });
            callback(events);
        }
```

In monthview it shows but when change to agendaweek view.. it not showing anything.

Can you please help?

Comment: strange- can you post one day of the xml that comes in-

Comment: you might need to explicitly state that 'allDay' => false in your xml. This is kind of similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6061311/664720)