# eventSources to events Json, full calendar

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar

I'm trying to get my json call from eventSources to my events.

The json I get back in my eventSources is :

```
[{"title":"Title Test","start":"1305841052"}]
```

When I past this string into events, it display's the date correctly.
Is there something i'm missing ?

Comment: What do you mean by not correctly (i assuemt thats what you meant) Is the time always 1 hour.. 2 hours.. 4 hours different? Try and return NOT UNIX time but ISO time with the Z in it to disable time zone data

Comment: If I manually add the string in Events like this : `events : [{"title":"Title Test","start":"1305841052"}]`  It works perfectly. But I have no idea how to do it automatically with a Json feed. How does it requires the markup of the Json feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you initialize the calendar, be sure to have the following:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    event: "json-feed.php",
    //more inits...
})
```

your json-feed.php file should look similar to the following:

```
<?php
    echo json_encode( array(
        array(
            'id' => 123,
            'title' => "myevent",
            'start' => "2011-05-24 10:05:00",
            'end' => "2011-05-24 11:55:00",
            'allDay' => false
         ),
         //more events...
     ));
?>
```